# In Java, does closing a parent input stream close its child, too?

Tags: java

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(gzipFile);
GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(fis);
gis.close();
fis.close();
```

Is fis.close() necessary? Though I'm running this code and don't seem to get any errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should see the implementation of `GZIPInputStream.close()`.

```
/**
 * Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated
 * with the stream.
 * @exception IOException if an I/O error has occurred
 */
public void close() throws IOException {
    if (!closed) {
        super.close();  
        eos = true;
        closed = true;
    }
}
```

If you take a look at the constructor for `GZIPInputStream`, it looks like this:

```
/**
 * Creates a new input stream with the specified buffer size.
 * @param in the input stream
 * @param size the input buffer size
 * @exception IOException if an I/O error has occurred
 * @exception IllegalArgumentException if size is <= 0
 */
public GZIPInputStream(InputStream in, int size) throws IOException {
super(in, new Inflater(true), size);
    usesDefaultInflater = true;
        readHeader(in);
}
```

Watch the variable `in`. Notice how it is being passed to the super class which is `InflaterInputStream` in this case.

Now, if we have a look at the implementation of `InflaterInputStream.close()` method, we will find this:

```
/**
 * Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated
 * with the stream.
 * @exception IOException if an I/O error has occurred
 */
public void close() throws IOException {
    if (!closed) {
        if (usesDefaultInflater)
            inf.end();
    in.close();
        closed = true;
    }
}
```

Clearly, `in.close()` is being called. So the wrapped (decorated) `FileInputStream` is also closed on the call to `GZIPInputStream.close()`. Thich makes calling `fis.close()` redundant.

Comment: `super` isn't the `FileInputStream`, it's the `close` method of the superclass of `GZIPInputStream`. Nothing (directly) to do with the input arguument to the constructor.

Comment: I don't see it in the source you linked, but if you have a look at the implementation of `super.close()` you'll see a line `in.close();` where `in` is the input stream that was passed to the constructor (`fis` in the OP's case).

Comment: In fact, it would seem that it is necessary. Calling `super.close()` does not mean closing the stream passed through parameter (in fact, you can be sure that `super.close()`does not make that, as it has not access to that attribute.

Comment: Yes, I agree on the fact that `super` isn't `FileInputStream`. But I will make the answer clearer. The wrapped stream is closed *indirectly*.

Comment: All of this investigation into implementation (which can change at any time) is caused by *poor documentation* in the `GZIPInputStream` and `InflaterInputStream`. *le sigh*

Comment: Thank you so much! And I agree with @T.J.Crowder that the documentation is poor--because I even tried to look into it.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those things that people need to clearly document. Unfortunately, `GZIPInputStream` overrides the `close` in its parent class and doesn't document what it does (poor documentation). But the odds are pretty high (even without looking at the code) that it will eventually call `super.close()` (and indeed we can see from adarshr's answer that it does, although you should never assume the implementation isn't going to change). If so, then we look at the docs for the parent class (`InflaterInputStream`). Unfortunately, it does exactly the same thing, overrides without documenting. But assume that it, too, calls `super.close()` at some point. Looking at *its* parent class (`FilterInputStream`) docs, it [explicitly says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#close%28%29) it does a `close` on the `in` member, which is set via the constructor. (A separate assumption is that `GZIPInputStream` and `InflaterInputStream` pass on the constructor argument to their superclasses, but that's very likely indeed.)

So `FilterInputStream` tells you clearly that it's going to close the stream you provide to the constructor. The odds are pretty high the others are going to call `super.close()`, even though they're poorly documented, so yes, it *should* close it for you and you shouldn't have to do it yourself. But there are some assumptions involved.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. The javadoc says:

> Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated
>   with the stream.

And the wrapped stream is definitely such a system resource.

Moreover, GZIPInputStream *is a* FilterInputStream, and the FilterInputStream javadoc says:

> Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated
>   with the stream. This method simply performs in.close().